# Two rows having null values merge into one row without null values

Tags: sql-server

I have fetched the record from table like this:

```
Name                 Opp                     Bid                  Pro
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Admin                 2                      NULL                 NULL
Pragnya Sonal         7                      NULL                 NULL
Priyanka Debnath      17                     NULL                 NULL
Sanjeev Sasmal        2                      NULL                 NULL
Subrajeet Sahoo       1                      NULL                 NULL
Pragnya Sonal         NULL                   2                    NULL
Pragnya Sonal         NULL                   NULL                 1
```

But I want to reorder this table in this format:

```
Admin                 2                      NULL                 NULL
Pragnya Sonal         7                      2                    1
Priyanka Debnath      17                     NULL                 NULL
Sanjeev Sasmal        2                      NULL                 NULL
Subrajeet Sahoo       1                      NULL                 NULL
```

Can any one help me to solve this, thank you very much in advance

Comment: try this `SELECT Name, SUM(Opp),SUM(Bid), SUM(Pro) FROM dbo.testCount GROUP BY Name`

Comment: check this [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/49dc3/2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use grouping to get only one row per Name. If more than one row for the same Name and column have values you have to decide what to do with those values: do you want to see minimum, maximum, sum, average etc? So for example:

```
SELECT Name, min(Opp), min(Bid), min(Pro) FROM your_table GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to achieve something similar to the Ops question but with a minor difference.  I was joining some tables and attempting to determine if a condition was "true" or not.  Thanks to the accepted answer by [@Simo Kivistö](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/58689/simo-kivist%C3%B6) I was able to adapt for my needs.

I was getting results similar to Op.  My City and States were being duplicated.

Original query:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE1.CITY,
    TABLE1.STATE,
    CASE WHEN TABLE2.COLUMNA IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IS_TRUE,
    CASE WHEN TABLE3.COLUMNZ IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IS_STUFF
FROM
    TABLE1
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE2.COLUMNA = TABLE1.STATE
    LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE3.COLUMNZ = TABLE1.STATE
```

Which resulted in the restuls below:

```
CITY                 STATE                   IS_TRUE              IS_STUFF
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Los Angeles           CA                     0                    1
Los Angeles           CA                     1                    0
Denver                CO                     1                    0
Denver                CO                     0                    0
```

I resolved using MAX() like so:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE1.CITY,
    TABLE1.STATE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TABLE2.COLUMNA IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS IS_TRUE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN TABLE3.COLUMNZ IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS IS_STUFF
FROM
    TABLE1
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE2.COLUMNA = TABLE1.STATE
    LEFT JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE3.COLUMNZ = TABLE1.STATE
GROUP BY
    TABLE1.CITY,
    TABLE1.STATE
```

Results:

```
CITY                 STATE                   IS_TRUE              IS_STUFF
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Los Angeles           CA                     1                    1
Denver                CO                     1                    0
```

Comment: I see you made a detailed answer that is likely very helpful.  Might I suggest you post your actual problem as a question (with similar care and details) - then post your nice answer - this will help more people find your answer - especially if they are having problem that you solve.